# Wordpress stripping <a href> from shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have a fairly straight forward shortcode for making a quote breakout box which is called as:

```
[jasminesays quote="blah de blah"]
```

Dead easy. However when I try and put a link inside it wordpress won't return the quote at all. All other HTML that I've tried seems fine, it only seems to fall over with something like:

```
[jasminesays quote="blah <a href="#">de</a> blah"]
```

Something like

```
[jasminesays quote="blah <p>de</p> blah"]
```

works fine.

The code to process the shortcode is:

```
function mm_jasmineSays( $atts ) { 
extract( shortcode_atts( array(  
        "quote" => '',
       ), $atts ) );

return '<link href="'.get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ).'/css/shortcodes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <div class="jasmine-says">
            <h2>Jasmine says...</h2>
            <div class="jasmine-says-quote">
                <p><img src="'.get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ).'/imgs/shortcodes/quote-1.jpg" /></p>
                <p class="quote">'.$quote.'</p>
                <p><img src="'.get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ).'/imgs/shortcodes/quote-2.jpg" /></p>
            </div>
        </div>';
}
add_shortcode('jasminesays', 'mm_jasmineSays');
```

but I don't think this is the problem, I'm guessing wordpress is filtering certain things out somewhere and I need to disable this. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

From [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

> The return value of a shortcode handler function is inserted into the
>   post content output in place of the shortcode macro. Remember to use
>   return and not echo - anything that is echoed will be output to the
>   browser, but it won't appear in the correct place on the page.
>
> Shortcodes are parsed after wpautop and wptexturize post formatting
>   has been applied (but see the note below about 2.5.0 and 2.5.1
>   differences). This means that your shortcode output HTML won't
>   automatically have curly quotes applied, p and br tags added, and so
>   on. If you do want your shortcode output to be formatted, you should
>   call wpautop() or wptexturize() directly when you return the output
>   from your shortcode handler.
>
> wpautop recognizes shortcode syntax and will attempt not to wrap p or
>   br tags around shortcodes that stand alone on a line by themselves.
>   Shortcodes intended for use in this manner should ensure that the
>   output is wrapped in an appropriate block tag such as p or div.

Comment: adding 

      $quote = apply_filters('the_content', $quote);

to the shortcode function doesn't seem to work, which seems odd. it just seems to be specifically picking on the <a> tags and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but have you tried changing the outer quotes to single quotes?

```
[jasminesays quote='blah <a href="#">de</a> blah']
```

or removing the inner quotes?

```
[jasminesays quote="blah <a href=#>de</a> blah"]
```

Answer (score 0):

why not adding the url option to the shortcode?

Something like adding:

```
    function mm_jasmineSays( $atts ) { 
extract( shortcode_atts( array(  
"quote" => '',
"url" => '',
), $atts ) );
```

And then adding

```
<a href="'.$url.'"> <h2>Jasmine says...</h2></a>
```

Maybe it could work..
or using the $output instead return like:

```
global $post;
$output .= '<div class="jasmine-says">';
if($quote !== '')
$output .= '<a href="'.$url.'"><h2>Jasmine says...</h2>';
        $output .= '<div class="jasmine-says-quote">'
            $output .='<p><img src="'.get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ).'/imgs/shortcodes/quote-1.jpg" /></p>';
            $output .='<p class="quote">'.$quote.'</p>';
            $output .='<p><img src="'.get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ).'/imgs/shortcodes/quote-2.jpg" /></p>';
        $output .='</div>';
    $output .='</div>';
```